# Tensorflow serving failing with std::bad_alloc

Tags: tensorflow, docker-compose, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to run tensorflow-serving using docker compose (served model + microservice) but the tensorflow serving container fails with the error below and then restarts.

```
microservice | To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
tensorflow-serving      | terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
tensorflow-serving      |   what():  std::bad_alloc
tensorflow-serving | /usr/bin/tf_serving_entrypoint.sh: line 3: 7 Aborted 
(core dumped) tensorflow_model_server --port=8500 --rest_api_port=8501 --model_name=${MODEL_NAME} --model_base_path=${MODEL_BASE_PATH}/${MODEL_NAME} "$@"
```

I monitored the memory usage and it seems like there's plenty of memory. I also increased the resource limit using Docker Desktop but still get the same error. Each request to the model is fairly small as the microservice is sending tokenized text with batch size of one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering the same problem, and this fixed worked for me:

- uninstalled and reinstalled:

  - `tensorflow`, `tensorflow-gpu`, etc to 2.9.0, (and trained and built my model)
  - `docker pull` and `docker run tensorflow/serving:2.8.0` (this did the trick and finally got rid of this problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error when using `tensorflow/serving:latest`. Based on Hanafi's response, I used `tensorflow/serving:2.8.0` and it worked.

For reference, I used

```
sudo docker run -p 8501:8501 --mount type=bind,source= \
[PATH_TO_MODEL_DIRECTORY],target=/models/[MODEL_NAME] \ 
-e MODEL_NAME=[MODEL_NAME] -t tensorflow/serving:2.8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved for `TensorFlow` and `TensorFlow Serving 2.11` (not yet released) and fix is included in nightly release of TF serving. You can build nightly [docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/serving/tags) image or use [pre-compiled version](https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests/releases/tag/serving-1.0.1).

Also TensorFlow `2.9` and `2.10` was patched to fix this issue. Refer PR here.[[1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/57952), [2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/57953)]